# Realizar envio de log em aplicação android na ocorrência de erros

Tags: java, android

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de enviar o log da aplicação, ou realizar alguma ação quando ocorre um erro em uma aplicação android (quando é exeibida a mensagem: "A aplicação parou de funcionar"). É possível fazer algo do tipo? Eu encontrei o Log Collector, mas como ele é uma aplicação separada, e como em androids acima de 4.1 as aplicações só podem ler os próprios logs, o Log Collector não funciona.

Comment: Não implementei nada do tipo, mas não seria possível criar um captador de erros, salvar no banco do celular e posteriormente enviar via web Service pra onde desejar ??

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias API's que fazem essa funcionalidade!
Recomendo as seguintes:

1. Crittercism - https://www.crittercism.com/
2. Crashlytics - https://www.crashlytics.com

Comment: Também tem o Flurry - http://www.flurry.com/