# Como criar relatório de erros de Aplicativo em Produção (Cliente)

Tags: java, android, log

Estou buscando uma forma (eficiente e prática) de capturar globalmente todas as Exceptions não tratadas pela aplicação (as que levam o aplicativo a *crash* ou "O aplicativo parou de funcionar!").

**Perguntas:**

- Há algum método `void main()`, como no Java que posso capturar estas
  exceções de forma centralizada, antes da aplicação dar *crash*?
- Há algum recurso disponível na API Android, para esses fins?
- Qual seria a forma mais eficiente e prática de criar este recurso?

**Gostaria de uma solução de implementação, não gostaria de utilizar bibliotecas de terceiros. Pois acredito que minha implementação final seria algo bem singular e especifico. =D**

> **Informações complementares**: O que deve ser possível fazer no capturador de Exceptions global (Recursos acessíveis) (Não é necessário implementar esses casos na resposta (são só informações necessárias para continuidade da implementação)):
>
> - Capturar a pilha de exceção;
> - Poder instanciar e utilizar o pacote `java.io`; (para gravação dos logs em arquivo)
> - (Opcional) Ter acesso ao `Context` da aplicação, para poder instanciar uma conexão ao SQLite; (para gravação dos logs em base de dados)

---

> **Obs:** Não pretendo tentar recuperar a aplicação, mas apenas ter essas informações para poder analisa-las e melhorar a eficiência da aplicação.
>
> Detalhe: Já vi [esta pergunta aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42491/realizar-envio-de-log-em-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-android-na-ocorr%C3%AAncia-de-erros) e não me auxiliou em minha duvida.

Comment: Sim Fernando, tem uma forma de fazer, vou criar uma resposta em breve.

Comment: Com certeza o *Wakim* deve detalhar muito bem uma solução, que acredito passar por aqui: [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exatamente como o [Paulo Rodrigues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4337/paulo-rodrigues) citou, o Android, mais especificamente a JVM, permite registrar um `Handler` para `Exception's` não tratadas.

E, acredito eu, que qualquer biblioteca que permita fazer o **report** de erros usa a mesma técnica.

## Tratando Exception's não capturadas

A forma mais simples e talvez organizada de fazer é usando a class `Application`. Onde no início da aplicação, no método `onCreate`, você registra o `Handler`.

Um exemplo que eu uso bastante:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultExceptionHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mDefaultExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        // Aqui você pode tratar a Exception...
        mDefaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
}
```

Ok, com apenas isso não responde toda pergunta. O `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` responde apenas a sua primeira pergunta.

Com o `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` acredito que seja possível responder as duas últimas, mas é preciso de um pouco mais de código.

## Escrevendo em arquivo

Para a segunda pergunta, eu tenho certeza que é possível, porque alguns dos tratamentos que eu faço em alguns app's é escrever em um arquivo o log do erro, mas eu costumo usar uma `Thread` separada para isso.

Uma forma simples:

```
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File file = new File("NOME_DO_ARQUIVO");
            FileWriter writer = null;

            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.write(throwableToString(ex));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
                close(writer);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private String throwableToString(Throwable t) {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter, false);

    t.printStackTrace(printWriter);

    printWriter.flush();
    stringWriter.flush();

    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

## Gravando a Exception no SQLite

Sim, é possível. Nunca cheguei a fazer isso, mas de acordo com esse [projeto](https://github.com/starfalling/tcclick-android/blob/master/src/com/truecolor/tcclick/UncaughtExceptionHandler.java), é possível.

Um exemplo mais enxuto ficaria:

```
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = new SeuSQLiteOpenHelper(Application.this).getWritableDatabase();

            String sql = "insert into exceptions(exception, created_at) values (?, ?)";

            Object args[] = {
                    throwableToString(ex),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
            };

            try { 
                db.execSQL(sql, args);
            } catch(Exception e){
            } finally {
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

E como alertado pelo Fernando, faltou a declaração da classe `Application` no **AndroidManifest**:

```
<application
    <!-- Demais atributos -->
    android:name=".application.Application" />
```

Comment: O caso do sqlite é simples, a implementação do projeto é que enrolou um pouco, talvez por causa do MD5. Vou colocar um exemplo mais enxuto.

Comment: Esse exemplo ficou ruim porque ele acaba encapsulando o acesso a banco para centralizar o código, mas no fundo ele só faz a chamada ao `TCClickUtil` pra acessar o `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Coloquei um exemplo mais compacto e que vai direto ao assunto.

Comment: Wakim, só uma observação em sua resposta verifiquei que a `class` _override_ `Application`, seu método `onCreate` não estava sendo chamado pela aplicação ao iniciar, então deduzi que talvez deveria ter alguma configuração no `manifest` da aplicação, então encontrei isso: <application android:name=".Application" ... > onde deve ser informado qual a `class` _override_ da Aplicação, no caso `android:name=".Application"`. Se possível adicione essa informação ao corpo da resposta, para deixar sua resposta ainda mais clara. =)

Comment: Eita, isso mesmo, é que eu já parti desse princípio, vou deixar mais claro para outros que venham depois não se percam. Vlw Fernando.

Answer (score 0):

**Alta manutenção!**

Uma implementação assim gera outros pontos de trabalho e 
mais manutenção, por exemplo! 
**1** - Criar uma forma de envio desse log. 
**2** - Controlar a repetição do envio do mesmo erro.( N users) 
**3** - Suportar carga de conexão e tráfego desse log. 
**4** - Minimizar a imagem negativa de um CRASH em seu aplicação 
**5** - Garantir que o envio de log seja feito mesmo ocorrendo um CRASH. 
**6** - Informar e pedir autorização ao usuário para enviar o log de erro 
e também informações adicionais para o mesmo. 
**7** - Implementar uma aplicação de recepção desses logs.

Algo mais profissional e trabalhado pensando nestes problemas seria!

[ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/) é uma biblioteca que permite O Aplicativo para Android postar automaticamente seus relatórios de falhas em uma forma de GoogleDoc(deprecated). É direcionado para desenvolvedores de aplicativos Android para ajudá-los a obter dados de suas aplicações quando deixam de funcionar ou se comportar erroneamente.

Mais informações: http://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup
                  https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends

Comment: Esses pontos podem ser relevantes para determinadas aplicações, já para outras, isso já não é sempre verdade, como em meu caso, onde é uma aplicação corporativa, onde já há um serviço responsável em receber e enviar informações para o aplicativo, onde não seria algo trabalhoso adicionar   essas informações de log. Também não há problemas em receber logs duplicados, pois podem informar vários ambientes em que o erro está ocorrendo e com que frequência. O log sendo feito manualmente ou com essa biblioteca citada não irá e nem deve tentar recuperar a aplicação de _"crashear"_ ...

Comment: ... continuando. Sendo assim para o usuário, não faz diferença. O envio será feito juntamento com o restante das informação já enviadas pelo aplicativo ao serviço, sendo garantida. E isso não exige nenhuma autorização ou intervenção do usuário, na verdade ele nem precisa saber que isso existe (principalmente, pelo fato de se tratar de uma aplicação corporativa).

Comment: @Fernando, vejo que suas necessidades são bem especificas e direcionadas para um ambiente coporativo fechado.  Essa solução vai muito além.

Comment: Apesar se não considerar adequado ao meu caso, é uma boa opção para os casos mais simples, onde já não há uma estrutura disponível e requisitos específicos. Só uma observação: A biblioteca citada não suporta mais reportar diretamente os Logs para o Docs do Google Drive: "The formKey parameter was used for the now deprecated GoogleDocs Forms backend. It is still required but not used anymore." (Fonte: [www.acra.ch](http://www.acra.ch/)) e isso é citado também no link que você postou: "Deprecated - a Google Docs spreadsheet (default and original behavior) - please read this notice beforehand"

Comment: @Fernando,  Assim como a própria API android, as (deprecated) ocorrem com a evolução do trabalho, isso mostra que a solução esta caminhando e evoluindo. As diversas formar de uso de ACRA com (third) em https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends!  Para avaliar o nível de aplicações suportados por ACRA é necessário uma avaliação bem extensa e complexa, mas já sendo visto que sua abrangência e muito grande, isso você pode confirmar nas avaliações do repositório  pelo gráfico de apoio de colaboradores.  https://github.com/ACRA/acra/graphs/contributors

Comment: Sim, talvez seja uma evolução, mas você citou o Google Drive como uma opção: "O Aplicativo para Android postar automaticamente seus relatórios de falhas em uma forma de GoogleDoc", e essa opção já não é mais valida e não deve ser utilizada.

Comment: Na descrição atual, isso não foi atualizado, somente na documentação é informado! Eu atualizei aqui também essa (deprecated).